# Using Waffle to toggle settings.py

Tags: django, django-settings

Are there any caveats with using [Waffle Switches](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-waffle) to conditionally change settings in my project's settings.py?
For instance, is it required to restart the Django process for the changes to take effect?
And if a restart *is* required, what is the best way to do this automatically?

Comment: What setting do you want to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created Waffle. It doesn't replace settings, or interact with them in the same way [constance](https://github.com/comoga/django-constance) is designed to.

There are things that could be either a setting, or a waffle switch, but those are two different ways to approach it.

```
from django.conf import settings
def my_function():
    if settings.SOME_SETTING:
        # do one thing
```

vs

```
from waffle import switch_is_active
def my_function():
    if switch_is_active('my-switch'):
        # do something
```

The big difference is that if you change a setting, you'll have to restart your Django process (unless the setting is used in a cron job or management command or something else that's not a web request). If you change a waffle switch, you don't need to restart anything.

And, just for completeness, to the last part of your question: waffle [flags](http://waffle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#using-waffle-in-views) require a request, because they have many criteria for being active, but samples and switches don't. Their value doesn't depend on a request.

Comment: I understand the difference between using `settings` and using `waffle`, I specifically wanted to use `waffle` to change the values in the `settings` files.  For instance, if a new `waffle switch` feature requires a different DB backend that is defined in settings.py.  So this answers my first question, that it's possible, but requires a restart.  BTW, nice app!